# Jira v.6.2 : Add comment to issue via C# WebRequest

Tags: c#, jira, jira-rest-api

I need to add a comment to an issue from c#. I read some article in jira api and so on but i still get a bad response (400).

This is the code i tried so far:

```
        string url = @"http://jira-test.ourcompany.de/rest/api/2/issue/" +
                     "IT-20175/comment?{\"body\":\"Test123\"}";

        WebRequest wrUrl = WebRequest.Create(url);
        wrUrl.ContentType = "application/json";
        wrUrl.Method = "POST";
        wrUrl.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert
            .ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(AuthInfo));            
        wrUrl.Method = "POST";

        Stream stream = wrUrl.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
```

This should add a comment "Test123" to issue IT-20175. But it doesnt work. Maybe someone can find my mistake?

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the comment JSON into your POST request body, not within the URL

URL: `http://jira-test.ourcompany.de/rest/api/2/issue/IT-20175/comment`

Body: `{"body":"Test123"}`

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working as expected. I feel dump because this is descriped in Jira Api too but i dont understand it there :D